# Left and right inverses of functions.

Tags: functions, inverse, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be the set of real transcendental numbers. Define the realtion $\sim$ on $X$ by $x\sim y$ iff $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$ is an equivalence relation.

Let $Y$ denote the set of equivalence classes generated by $\sim$ defined above.

Define the function $P:X \rightarrow Y$ by $f(x) = [x]$ where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$. Does the function P have:

- a left inverse?
- a right inverse?

My work so far:

Since $P$ is surjective by definition of equivalence classes, $P$ has a right inverse.

Now if $P$ is injective then it will have a left inverse. I think it's not injective as two real transcendental numbers can end up in the same equivalence class, so $P$ doesn't have a left inverse, but I am not sure how to show this rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: prove that if $x\in X$, then also $x+1\in X$. Since $x+1\sim x$, the map $P$ is not injective

Hint 2: the sum of algebraic numbers is algebraic.

Comment: I am having trouble doing the first bit. I know the algebraic numbers form a field. So the sum of algebraic numbers is algebraic. So since $x$ is transcendental $x+1$ can't be algebraic?

Comment: @xAly $(x+1)-x=1\in\mathbb{Q}$, so $x+1\sim x$. If $x+1$ is algebraic, then also $(x+1)-1=x$ is algebraic.

Comment: But $X$ is the set of real transcendental numbers, not algebraic numbers?

Comment: @xAly Yes. This proves that if $x$ is transcendental, then also $x+1$ is.

Comment: Ah ok. If $x$ is transcendental and $x+1$ were algebraic, that would be impossible because then $x$ would have to be algebraic. That took me a bit...

Comment: @xAly Don't worry! You're welcome.